# ILogger and DependencyInjection in ASP.NET Core 2+

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

I notice there is no explicit `ILogger` registration in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`.

First question: how does `ILogger` get injected into e.g. controllers.

Second question: how do I configure `ILogger` to get injected into middleware?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Logging is added as part of the [HostBuilder.Build](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/HostBuilder.cs#L102) process

```
private void CreateServiceProvider()
{
    var services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton(_hostingEnvironment);
    services.AddSingleton(_hostBuilderContext);
    services.AddSingleton(_appConfiguration);
    services.AddSingleton<IApplicationLifetime, ApplicationLifetime>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, ConsoleLifetime>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHost, Host>();
    services.AddOptions();
    services.AddLogging();//<--HERE

    //...
```

[WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L211)

```
    private IServiceCollection BuildCommonServices(out AggregateException hostingStartupErrors)
    {

        //... code removed for brevity

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton(_options);
        services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(_hostingEnvironment);
        services.AddSingleton<Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment>(_hostingEnvironment);
        services.AddSingleton(_context);

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
            .AddConfiguration(_config);

        _configureAppConfigurationBuilder?.Invoke(_context, builder);

        var configuration = builder.Build();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
        _context.Configuration = configuration;

        var listener = new DiagnosticListener("Microsoft.AspNetCore");
        services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticListener>(listener);
        services.AddSingleton<DiagnosticSource>(listener);

        services.AddTransient<IApplicationBuilderFactory, ApplicationBuilderFactory>();
        services.AddTransient<IHttpContextFactory, HttpContextFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IMiddlewareFactory, MiddlewareFactory>();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddLogging();
```

To get `ILogger` injected into a controller just include it in the constructor  as a dependency

```
private readonly ILogger logger;

public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger) {
    this.logger = logger;
}

//...
```

and the framework will inject it into the controller when it is being activated.

Reference [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

The same can be done for Middleware vai constructor injection just like with the controller,

or directly into the `Invoke` method for [per-request dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#per-request-dependencies)

```
public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILogger<MyMiddleware> logger) {
    //...
}
```

like any other injected service

Reference [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index)

Comment: Very well written response.  Thanks.  It seems the per-request dependencies are limited.  For example, I am not able to inject an ILogger into `Invoke`. Do you know where details on per-request dependencies are documented?